# Every computational task can be solved with $O(1)$ additional memory

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, computability

We were wondering, is it true that no matter which complexity we solve the problem with, it can be solved using $O(1)$ additional memory? Does it refer to a kind of unsolved computational math problem or can be easily proofed (disproofed)?

Comment: How did this question arise? Why would you think it is true?

Comment: If this were true, we wouldn't have complexity classes such as [EXPSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE).

Comment: This question, honestly, was risen out of nowhere.

Comment: >If this were true, we wouldn't have complexity classes such as EXPSPACE.

But does it imply that additional memory will be used as well? Maybe there is an algorithm that solves the problem for a really long time, but still uses O(1)?

Comment: @mamamialogic EXPSPACE is explicitly about exponential *space*, not time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) proves that this is false. In fact, it shows that for a large class of functions $f$, there are problems which can be solved using $O(f(n))$ bits of memory, but not $o(f(n))$ bits.

Just take $f(n)$ to be any function that grows with $n$.